# Update table fields from an other table conditionaly

Tags: mysql

I have this query, my aim is to update products table more precisely the "model" field, using data from the Model table, the condition here is to get the model name, see what the id is from model table and brand name from the products tables

```
UPDATE products
SET products.model = (SELECT Model.id FROM Model, Brand
                      WHERE Brand.id = Model.id_brand
                          AND Brand.title = 'ALCATEL'
                          AND Model.title = products.model)
WHERE products.brand = 'ALCATEL'
```

Comment: And the problem is?..

Comment: sorry @sagi "noting is updated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update products set products.model = (select Model.id from Model, Brand where Brand.id = Model.id_brand and Brand.title = 'ALCATEL' and Model.title = products.model) where products.brand = 'ALCATEL'
```

Here in your sub query you can return only one column and it's mandatory it's return only single value so need to use LIMIT 1. Below is modified sub query.

```
select Model.id from Model INNER JOIN Brand ON Brand.id = Model.id_brand where Brand.title = 'ALCATEL' and Model.title = products.model LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it does since its a jointure of two tables, i get the brand title from a table and the model table have the brand id and model name and the model id but the sub-query have the products.model in where clause and the "products.model" is from the outside of the sub-query not sur if thats even possible

Comment: Can I know error description after updating a sub query as I mentioned above?

Comment: runing the query as a select your sub-query give me "NULL"

Comment: Can I have your table design?